# Error while adding service reference to client WCF

Tags: wcf, service-reference, net.tcp

I am working with persession instance and i have created a service with net.tcp binding and a client when i am adding the reference i am getting an error like

Contract requires Session, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it.

my web.config

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   </system.web>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" portSharingEnabled="true">

          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="servicbeha" name="asdad">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          name="tcpbind" contract="Wcfexam.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="mextcp" bindingName="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://chandu-PC:8080/Wcfexam/Service1.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
     </services>
     <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="servicbeha">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you might want to look at is that you have serviceMetadata turned off. No client will ever be able to discover your endpoint if you don't publish it. Once you enable it you need to provide a http address to publish the data.

Comment: As i am using net.tcp i think there is no need to enable servicemetadata,even though i have set to true still the same error.

Comment: as Stephenl mentioned you will have to provide a http address to publish the data. When u add a service reference in VS, svcutil.exe will look for this http address to retreive the information

Comment: @chandrasekhar How are you hosting it? What version of WCF are you using?